# WebBroker DataSnap in Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, iis, delphi-xe3, datasnap, webbroker

I'm working on a project with WebBroker DataSnap in Delphi XE3.

First I created a DataSnap Server WebBroker VCL exclusively using the wizard, `TDSServerModule` inheriting the class and ran to port 8085.

After I created the client application (`MyApp.exe`), also using the wizard (Class Client and Client Module), and connected to the server successfully.

Now I decided to host the DataSnap Server WebBroker in IIS 7.5 Express, so I created a new server with WebBroker DataSnap ISAPI, using the same units of the first server, but a new port 8090.

I configured IIS 7.5 Express, following the tutorial Embarcadero. (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40873)

Using the browser, when I access the address `localhost:8090/myserver/srvweb.dll`, I get the "DataSnap Server" message.

I believe this means that the DataSnap server in IIS is configured properly and available to clients.

But when I modify the client (MyApp.exe) and direct it to port 8090 (IIS) and put in URLPath `/myserver/srvweb.dll`, I get the message

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method not Allowed"

What is missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this was long ago... but you didn't tell us anything about how your client calls the server. Where's the code for your client?